# regex for something followed by alphanumeric

Tags: regex

what would be the regex for the following. The field should contain and start with : "AN=" which will be followed by only alphanumeric characters i.e aA1-zZ0

Comment: And what have you been trying?

Comment: As per the [tag:regex] tag, "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using"

Comment: @anubhava, I think OP is trying to express the concept of the ranges `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `0-9`, but that's only a guess on my part.

Comment: Some test input would also be a nice thing to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets guess its perl, because perl is of course the most awesome place to do regex :-)

```
/^AN=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

So you have `^` which says the pattern has to match at the beginning of the target string.  Then the literal `AN=`.  Then a set `[]` of valid characters `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` (order is not important here) and a `+` to say that there has to be at least one of these characters.  And finally a `$` to say that the allowed characters have to go all the way to the end of the field (ie there can't be anything else left over).

Comment: You should add an end anchor so that that something like `AN=abc123!` would not pass.

Comment: I wasn't clear on my first reading that the entire field has to be matched.  Thanks.

Comment: @woolstar - Also, could you modify the regex to make the AN= optional. As in if AN= is present then it should be followed by alphanumeric, but if AN= is not present then anything can be written.

Comment: Yes, but why would you want that?